# Delete row by row number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, delete-row, sql-delete

I am new to postgreSql and I used following query to retrieve all the fields from database.

```
SELECT student.*,row_number() OVER () as rnum FROM student;
```

I don't know how to delete particular row by row number.Please give me some idea.

This is my table:

```
Column      | Type
------------+------------------
name        | text
rollno      | integer 
cgpa        | double precision 
department  | text 
branch      | text
```

Comment: Please show your table schema. Do you have a primary key defined on the table?

Comment: Table "public.student"
   Column   |       Type       | Modifiers 
------------+------------------+-----------
 name       | text             | 
 rollno     | integer          | 
 cgpa       | double precision | 
 department | text             | 
 branch     | text             |

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR dont you have any `unique` filed in your table ??

Answer (score 6):

```
with a as
(
SELECT student.*,row_number() OVER () as rnum FROM student
)

delete from student where ctid in (select ctid from a where rnum =1) -- the 
                                                                     -- row_number you want    
                                                                     -- to delete
```

---

Quoted from [PostgreSQL - System Columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

> **ctid :**
>   
> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note
>   that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very
>   quickly, a row's ctid will change each time it is updated or moved by
>   VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier.
>   The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used
>   to identify logical rows.

---

Note :  I strongly recommend you to use an `unique` filed in *student* table.

---

As per [Craig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374632/delete-row-by-row-number-in-postgresql/26375120?noredirect=1#comment41408841_26375120), I'll give another way to solve OP's issue it's a bit tricky

First create a unique *column* for *table* `student`, for this use below *query*

```
alter table student add column stu_uniq serial
```

this will produce `stu_uniq` with corresponding unique values for each row, so that OP can easily `DELETE` any *row(s)* using this `stu_uniq`

Comment: Here what is ctid? In this table I can have duplicate data so I can't delete by any field value.For example I can have rollno value as 100 in multiple rows.When i try to delete with id it'll delete all the rows with rollno as 100.

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR did you try my answer ?? in my answer i have clearly mentioned about **ctid** or just refer http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR every table in `PostgreSQL` have a `CTID` if you want to check in your case try _select ctid,* from student_

Comment: @WingedPanther: please don't use links to outdated versions (especially if it's that old as 8.2). Use `current` instead of the version number to link to an up-to-date version of the manual.

Comment: Your linked contained the version `8.2`

Comment: This advice is extremely dangerous. Don't do this unless you know exactly what you are doing. `ctid` is not a substitute for a primary key. This will silently fail to update concurrently updated rows.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes you're correct.I just posted a way to do OP's _question_, I recommended to use an `unique` _column_ for his table

Comment: @WingedPanther:I can't have a unique field here,because in my problem am reading data from file and storing directly into database.I am displaying the data in html table and I need to delete record by checking checkbox, for example Mail deletion.

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR: you can still have a `serial` column in that table which is then automatically populated during the import (just don't provide a value for it). This will be a much better solution than relying on the ctid.

Comment: Saved my day! Thnks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether its a correct alternative for this problem.But it satisfies my problem.What my problem is I need to delete a row without help of anyone of it's column.I created table with OIDS,and with help of oid I deleted the rows.

```
CREATE TABLE Student(Name Text,RollNo Integer,Cgpa Float,Department Text,Branch Text)WITH OIDS;
 DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE oid=18789;
 DELETE FROM STUDENT WHERE oid=18790;
```

Quoted from PostgreSQL - [System Columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

Thanks to @WingedPanther for suggesting this idea.

Answer (score -3):

You could try like this.

```
create table t(id int,name varchar(10));
insert into t values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d');


with cte as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id) as rn from t
)
delete from cte where rn=1;
```

[Cte in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: with cte as(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over() as rn from student)delete from cte where rn=1;                                               I used this query but am getting an error like this.         ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist
LINE 1: ...OW_NUMBER() over() as rn from student)delete from cte where ...

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR Which `PostgreSQL` version your using ??

Comment: my psql version is 9.3.5. But this command working for select query.   with CTE as(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over() as rn from student)select * from cte;

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR if possible update your question with that table structure and some sample data

Comment: I need to delete a row by its row number.My Student table has 5 fields such as name,rollno,department,branch,cgpa. For example Ganesh,100,MCA,CA,7.5

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle demo for your question? www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 _CTE in PostgreSQL works differently, you cannot delete or update it_

Comment: Yep, unfortunaetly [CTEs in PostgreSQL are forced-materialisation optimisation fences that cannot be treated as simply-updatable views](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/). So you can't `DELETE FROM` a CTE term.